# How to embed leaflet map to html page?

Tags: html, dictionary, web, embed, leaflet

I'm new to web developing, and I want to embed a map on my HTML page.

How can I do this?

I'm using a leaflet map generated from QuantumGIS with qgis2leaflet plugins.
In the future, I want to show a heat graph on the map representing population distribution.

this is my HTML code:

```
<div class="widget span8">
        <div class="widget-header">
          <i class="icon-map-marker"></i>
          <h5>Map Visualization</h5>
          <div class="widget-buttons">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-body clearfix">
          <div style="height:274px;" id="graph" class="widget-analytics-large"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you followed [this](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/leaflet_maps_with_qgis2leaf.html) tutorial, I think it cover all aspects

Comment: yes, i was following that tutorial and succeeded to create the leaflet map.
Now, I want to put that leaflet map to my own html page. How I can do that? @muzaffar

Answer (score 3):

Have a look here: http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html
This is an example page: http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start-example.html

generally, you would have to add a placeholder div for your map in the body

```
<div id="my-custom-map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
```

and then create the leaflet map via the Javascript API:

```
var map = L.map('my-custom-map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6IjZjNmRjNzk3ZmE2MTcwOTEwMGY0MzU3YjUzOWFmNWZhIn0.Y8bhBaUMqFiPrDRW9hieoQ', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(map);
```

Note that you are using the id of the element (my-custom-map) to create the leaflet map within that div